# webbrowser iframes open in default browser

Tags: c#, browser

I've got the WebBrowser control to open links in my default browser like this:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.ToString() != "about:blank")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Url.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This works great but if I load a document that contains some IFrame elements those will be opened in the system browser as well (mostly embedded stuff, like Google Maps, Digg icons, etc..).

How do I keep iframes loading in the Webbrowser control and user clicked links in the system browser?

Comment: You have a WebBrowser control in your Windows Form. And you want some Urls to be launched in the OS's browser and some within your form window?

Comment: Exactly. The way I'm doing it now is less than optimal. Page elements like iframe trigger the Navigating event, so I get parts of a page "popping-up" in Firefox while the rest (like images) loads quietly in the Webbrowser control.

Only user-clicked links should open in the default browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that the .NET WebBrowser component is almost useless in this regard. I've tried to read `WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs.TargetFrameName` but it will return the `name` attribute of the iframe element only if the HTML document has it. Otherwise it will spit out an empty `""` string. Returning null on non-frame links would have been tons more useful.

So the only fix I've found for this is using the AxWebBrowser control, and specifically listening to the BeforeNavigate2 event. I haven't tested as much as I should have, but it appears that the "flags" property in `DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2Event` is set to **64** each time it's user triggered.

```
private void axWebBrowser1_BeforeNavigate2(object sender, AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2Event e)
{
    // 64 means user triggered
    if ((int)e.flags == 64 && e.uRL.ToString() != "about:blank")
    {
        e.cancel = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.uRL.ToString());
    }
}
```

MSDN docs says that `flags` is an IE7+ only parameter, so I have no idea what happens on IE6 machines...

[Using Internet Explorer from .NET](http://www.webtropy.com/articles/InternetExplorer.asp) has some really valuable information regarding AxWebBrowser.

Comment: also to note, it's not necessary to use the COM control. You can easily expand WebBrowser to hook into the required events (in this case, BeforeNavigate2) as described at http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2008/09/18/newwindow2-events-in-the-c-webbrowsercontrol.aspx

Comment: finally got to test this on IE6 and what do you know? it works. Yay!