# How to detect navigation in TWebBrowser as opposed to clicking URLs?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm using a `TWebBrowser` to display some HTML content (locally). The application is split in half, the top half has 5 tabs and the bottom half is the web browser. The contents of the browser change often, for example when changing to a different tab.

The content which is shown includes URLs which I need to prevent and stop every click. I'm trying to use the event `OnBeforeNavigate2` which does detect every link clicked, but also detects when I programatically call `Navigate`. So, it winds up never navigating anywhere.

I tried wrapping the `Navigate` call so I always call something like...

```
procedure TForm1.Nav(const S: String);
begin
  FLoading:= True;
  try
    Web.Navigate(S);
    Sleep(50);
  finally
    FLoading:= False;
  end;
end;
```

(Sleep was just to try and give it a split second to wait)

And then capturing the call...

```
procedure TForm1.WebBeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
  const URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant;
  var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  if not FLoading then
    Cancel:= True;
end;
```

No luck trying this trick. How can I detect when the page or user navigates but not when the browser is instructed to navigate?

Comment: Although TLama answered this quite nicely, I thought I'd point out my next solution would have been sloppy: whenever I call `TWebBrowser.Navigate()` include a dummy query string such as `&bypass=Y` and do a search for that query parameter in the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that the following is undocumented. Some [`people say`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1683363/960757) and it works for me (on Windows 7 64-bit, with Internet Explorer 10) to check for *a magical constant* of the `Flags` parameter. If the `Flags` parameter of the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event equals to 64, it was the user, who navigated through the link. If the `Flags` parameter equals to 0, it was the [`IWebBrowser2::Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, who invoked the navigation. In code it would be:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  if (Flags and navHyperlink) = navHyperlink then
    ShowMessage('User clicked a link...')
  else
    ShowMessage('IWebBrowser2::Navigate has been invoked...');
end;
```

I wouldn't be much surprised, if that is just unintentionally undocumented flag value because that part of the MSDN is horrible.

Comment: It makes me feel like it was the [`navHyperlink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565688(v=vs.85).aspx) flag value passed from the navigation event...

Answer (score 0):

I used this way to get full URL plus hash tags:

```
uses Winapi.ShellAPI, UnitFaktorMain, MsHtml;

procedure TfrmIntro.wb1NewWindow3(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch; var Cancel: WordBool; dwFlags: Cardinal; const bstrUrlContext, bstrUrl: WideString);
var
  vAdr     :string;
begin
  Cancel:= True;
  try
    vAdr := ((TWebBrowser(ASender).Document as IHTMLDocument2).ActiveElement as IHTMLElement).GetAttribute('href', 0);
  except
    vAdr:= bstrUrl;
  end;
  ShellExecute(Handle,
               'open',
               PWideChar(vAdr),
               nil,
               nil,
               SW_SHOW);
end;

procedure TForm1.wb2BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  if (Flags and navHyperlink) = navHyperlink then begin
    Cancel:= True;
    ShellExecute(Handle,
               'open',
               PWideChar(VarToStr(URL)),
               nil,
               nil,
               SW_SHOW);
  end;
end;
```